# Can I use chainlink on a private blockchain？

Tags: private-blockchain, oracles, chainlink

Can I use chainlink on a private blockchain built with Geth? I found that the online tutorials are basically about how to use chainlink on the Kovan test chain. I want to know whether chainlink can be used on a private blockchain?

Hope you can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Chainlink's contracts are open source ([here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink), MIT license), so you could take them and implement them on a private blockchain (assuming said blockchain supports Solidity).

Without the contracts being reimplemented and redeployed on the private blockchain, there wouldn't be any oracles on the private chain to contact. The addresses mentioned in the Chainlink docs are to contacts deployed on the Ethereum mainnet, but they (like any other contract) do not automatically appear in other blockchain networks that are spun up.

All of this means that Chainlink will only exist on a private chain if someone implements it there, and will only be as robust and decentralized as the oracle node runners on the private chain.